# Function that will only push value of most recent inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 groups of inputs, in chronological order (manufacturer info, repair info, test info). When the user hits the "confirm button", I want an if statement to iterate through each input, compare if `(input.val() !== "")`, and then make sure it is the most recent data (ie. repair info will supercede mfg info) before pushing that value to the #asreceived fields.

I have manually done an if statement for each set of inputs to iterate through, however I would have to add to the function if I wanted to enter more fields.

This is what I have currently:

```
  $("#model-received").val(function() {
    if ($("#model-test").val() != "") {
      return $("#model-testonly").val();
    } else if ($("#model-repair").val() != "") {
      return $("#model-repair").val();
    } else {
      return $("#model-initial").val();
    }
  });
```

I have used this code for each set of inputs (roughly 50)

I have tried to compare groups using the .each(), but I am stuck here.

```
let $inputMfg = $("#manufacturers-tag").find("input , select").each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr("name").indexOf("-initial") > -1) {
        return
      }
    });
let $inputRep = $("#repairtag-old").find("input , select").each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr("name").indexOf("-repair") > -1) {
        return
      }
    });
let $inputTO = $("#testonlytag-old").find("input , select").each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr("name").indexOf("-testonly") > -1) {
        return
      }
    });
let $inputAsRec = $("#asreceived").find("input , select").each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr("name").indexOf("-received") > -1) {
        return
      }
    });
```

`$("#asreceived"),$("#testonlytag-old"),$("#repairtag-old"),$("#manufacturers-tag")` are all the same HTML, minus the name suffix on each input ("-initial")

HTML

```
<div id="repairtag-old" hidden>
            <div class="entry-col3">
              <div class="entry-line">
                <label class="entry-label">Company: </label>
                <input class="entry-input" type="text" name="company-repair">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="entry-col3">
              <div class="entry-line">
                <label class="entry-label">Date: </label>
                <input class="entry-date" type="date" name="date-repair">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="entry-col3">
              <div class="entry-line">
                <label class="entry-label">VR Stamp: </label>
                <select class="entry-select" id="vrstamp-old" name="vrstamp-old">
                  <option></option>
                  <option>Yes</option>
                  <option>No</option>
                </select>
                <label class="entry-bylabel">VR: </label>
                <input class="entry-input" type="text" name="vrnumber-old">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="entry-col2">
              <div class="entry-line">
                <label class="entry-label">Job Number: </label>
                <input class="entry-input" type="text" name="jobnumber-repair">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="entry-col2">
              <div class="entry-line">
                <label class="entry-label">Model Number: </label>
                <input class="entry-input" id="model-repair" type="text" name="model-repair">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="entry-col3">
              <div class="entry-line">
                <label class="entry-label">Set Pressure: </label>
                <input class="entry-input" id="setpressure-repair" type="text" name="setpressure-repair">
                <select class="entry-select" name="setunit-repair">
                  <option>psig</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="entry-col3">
              <div class="entry-line">
                <label class="entry-label">Cold Test Pressure: </label>
                <input class="entry-input" type="text" name="coldpressure-repair">
                <select class="entry-select" name="coldunit-repair">
                  <option>psig</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="entry-col3">
              <div class="entry-line">
                <label class="entry-label">Capacity: </label>
                <input class="entry-input" type="text" name="capacity-repair">
                <select class="entry-select" name="capacityunit-repair">
                  <option>scfm</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <br>
          </div>
```

The final result should push the value of the most important value (test only 1st, repair 2nd, mfg 3rd). If the `(input.val === "")`, it should use the older values.

---UPDATED---

I figured it out. Code snippet below. Thank you for the responses, I was a little intimated in trying to implement them (I am new at coding). However, Mark Meyer's response got me on the right track. This works exactly as intended.

```
$("#copybtn-received").click(function(i) {
    $("#asreceived").find("input, select").each(function() {
      let $output = $(this).attr("name").split("-received")[0];
      let $inputTO = $("#testonlytag-old").find("[name^=" + $output + "]");
      let $inputRep = $("#repairtag-old").find("[name^=" + $output + "]");
      let $inputMfg = $("#manufacturers-tag").find("[name^=" + $output + "]");
      if ($inputTO.val() !== "") {
        $(this).val($inputTO.val());
      } else if ($inputRep.val() !== "") {
        $(this).val($inputRep.val());
      } else if ($inputMfg.val() !== "") {
        $(this).val($inputMfg.val());
      } else {
        $(this).val("");
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put your values in an array that is in the order of precedence you want then use `find()` which returns the first value found. In the find callback just return whether the value is truth, which `""` isn't. This will allow you to decide arbitrary orders without all the `if/else` statements.

Here's a simplified example. It will log the highest value filled in.

```js
function getBest(){
  /* values in the order values will be found */
  let values = [
    document.getElementById("one").value,
    document.getElementById("two").value,
    document.getElementById("three").value,
    document.getElementById("four").value
  ]

  /* find the first truthy value */
  let best = values.find(val => val)

  console.log(best)
}
```

```html
<input id="one" type ="text"><br />
<input id="two" type ="text"><br />
<input id="three" type ="text"><br />
<input id="four" type ="text"><br />


<button onclick="getBest()">Go</button>
```

Comment: This got me on the right track. I have updated the OP to show the new code snippet. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question correctly, so this is a bit of a guess.  Perhaps something like this would do?:

```js
const findFirst = (ids, idx = ids.find(id => $(`#${id}`).val() !== '')) =>
    idx > -1 ? $(`#${id}`).val() : 'not found'

$("#model-received").val(findFirst(
    ['model-testonly', 'model-repair', 'model-initial']
))
```

You can then update the list by simply appending to that array.  And if the `'model-'` prefix is universal, you can include that in the function and only pass `['testonly', 'repair', 'initial']` in the call.

I don't know if you have a better default than the 'not found' here.